# How to check if string contains ONLY one space?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know that if I want to check for more than 1 space I can do this:

```
  if (str.match(".*  .*")) { 
       console.log('String contains more than 1 space');
   }
```

But how to check if string has ONLY ONE string like:  "t "  or " t"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match strings that have some number of non-spaces, then a single space, and then more non-spaces to the end of the string:

```
var oneSpace = /^[^ ]* [^ ]*$/;
```

The `^` and `$` anchors are important because the pattern only matches the complete string and not just parts.

Comment: can you provide an example on how to use your regex? Thanks

Comment: @progx `if (oneSpace.test(someString)) alert("1 space!");`

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A possible non-RE solution (perhaps faster) would be to use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), like so:

```
let spaces = str.split(" ").length - 1;
if (spaces > 1) { 
  console.log('String contains more than 1 space');
}
```

Comment: Hm, yep I thought the same but I think Pointy's answer is what the OP wants (very vague question though).

Comment: @JohnnyHK Absolutely :)